# Switching the Employer after I-140 approved

Tags: usa, greencard

I am working in USA with H1B. My employer initiated my green card process and my I-140 is in progress. I am working at client location and my employer is vendor to current client.

My Client shown interest to me giving an opportunity of full time Employe position. I am considering this opportunity.

On this context, below is my questions.

After I-140 approved can I change my Employer? If yes what is the process?
Can I change my employer Immediately or I have to serve any waiting period after my I-140 approved?
I would like to retain my I-140 status and also my priority Date. What my new employer has to do in order to do that and what I have to do?

Comment: There is some hearsay information here -http://www.greatandhra.com/articles/special-articles/can-i-change-employers-after-i-140-76429.html and https://www.quora.com/Can-I-change-jobs-6-months-after-I-14 and https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=9a21af17-b4db-4e1d-b170-d96825a7e6c50-approval-which-is-the-first-step-for-a-green-card